# Reducing image size for Facebook

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, jpg

I need to resize a .jpg for placement in Facebook business page.

I've tried both scaling in AI as well as reducing the pixel size significantly, but when I upload the image it still does not fit in the space.

The outside edges of the image are cut off.

I must be going about this the wrong way. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you mean that the aspect ratio of your image is wrong, in comparison to what the site wants?

Answer (score -1):

You need to open it up in an image editor such as Illustrator, GIMP, paint.net, etc.

And then usually they have the ability to resize an image to any size, and if you need to change the aspect ratio, they give you the option to either stretch the image or add bars on either side.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).